# How can I detect when UITextField changed and trigger an alert?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to detect when the user change the input field.

I created this function

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Did you bring your towel?", message: "It's recommended you bring your towel before continuing.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)

}
```

I added my Target like this

`passWord.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(passWord:)), for: .editingChanged)`

I kept getting this error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'textFieldDidChange(passWord:)'

[image]

How do I prevent this error to happen ?

Comment: Where should I make that changes ?

Comment: Did you implement such a method: `textFieldDidChange(passWord:)`? Because the compiler is saying it doesn't knows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong…

```
passWord.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

Comment: You should probably update the title of your question - it's really about the error message

Comment: What do you mean this _"is NOT the Apple way…"_? Have you actually tried this? Have you bothered to read Apple's documentation… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618241-editingchanged ?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way for this,
simply create password textfield event.